How to get HTTP request, then share the info with a Gateway provider. Nest.js
Task:
I'm trying to get HTTP request that the user leaves the chat room. This information ought to be shared with others in this chat. To be more precise, step by step:

the user clicks button "leave room X-name-room";
front end sends an HTTP request;
here is some logic that allows the user to leave the room
the HTTP controller transmits information about the HTTP request to the websocket service(Nest.Gateway)
the Ws service sends a message "user-leave-a-room" event to the participants of the room;
an http response is sent to the user, who left the room.


Problem:
I can't find information about the data exchange between Nest.Controller and Nest.Gateways(ws).
Prerequisites:
Now I just do it only via Websocket event. But in this case, the user interface cannot know the exact time, when the user left a room. (an HTTP request can be awaited via promises, and websocket event - can't).

Workaround:
Front end sends an HTTP request to leave a room. Awaiting a response. Then sends a socket event to notify the room participants. But the interface hasn't to care of other local machines of the service users - this is wrong. This task should be up to server side.
Thanks a lot for your answers.

So, I've found a solution to the problem:
Nest.js allows you to simply integrate Nest.Gateways into other classes, including Nest.Controllers. In this way, we can:

receive an HTTP request
process this one
send out socket events
return an HTTP response

Simplified code:
// events.gateway.ts file
import { SubscribeMessage, WebSocketGateway, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect } from '@nestjs/websockets';

@WebSocketGateway()
export class EventsGateway implements OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {
  handleConnection(client: any, ...args: any[]) {
    console.log('Client connected:', client.id);
  }

  handleDisconnect(client: any) {
    console.log('Client disconnected:', client.id);
  }

  @SubscribeMessage('msgToServer')
  handleMessage(client: any, payload: string): string {
    return 'Message received: ' + payload;
  }
}


// room.controller.ts file
import { Controller, Post, Body, HttpCode, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { EventsGateway } from './events.gateway';

@Controller('room')
export class RoomController {
  // here we just inject the SocketGateway service
  constructor(private eventsGateway: EventsGateway) {}

  // when a user leaves a room:

  // P.S: you should get the userId from the sessions or JWT tokens. I've 
  // included the 'userId' field in the request.Body just for clarity.
  @Delete('leave')
  @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
  leaveRoom(@Body() data: { roomId: string, userId: string }) {
    this.eventsGateway.server
        .to(roomId)
        .emit('room:user-leaves', data.message);
  }
}

